# Constructing a more efficient javascript user-based chat

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am going to bed soon, so I will not be on until the morning, but I have been struggling with trying to find a javascript/jquery method that solves my problem.  I am trying to make a chat box feature where once a post is submitting it is then echoed back out and users on both ends can see it.  I know that I need to use javascript and or jquery.  Right now I am using a very inefficiency system:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    setInterval( function() {
    $('#responsechat').load('echogetconversation.php?username=<?php echo   $username; ?>&otherchatuser=<?php echo $otherchatuser; ?>');
    }, 100);
    </script>
```

The only reason that I am using it is because it is the only way I know how to project new posts to both users.  I was wondering if someone knew a way to do this.  Once a post is submitted, it fades into a div and both users can see it, not only the user who submitted it, so it is like a facebook chat in a way.  I have no idea about any possible solutions, and have done research, but I could not find any that i could get to work.  Any help and/or insight to what I should do next would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology cool kid is WebSockets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is ajax long pulling, also called Comet (it's a silly pun). The basic idea is simple--instead of polling the server, you send your ajax request and the server *blocks* on it until it gets a new message.

"Blocking" here simply means it does not send a response. You get your request then first up a thread (is that what you would do in PHP? I've only ever used node.js for this) and wait until something changes before sending the response back to the client.

Once the client has a response, it sends another request immediately.

There is one other trick: requests can time out. This means that the server should send a response back after a certain time even if nothing has updated.

This methodology is good if you have to support older browsers; if you can ignore those and stick to newer ones, you can use "websockets".

There are libraries that help you use websockets or fall back on Comet. I think the most popular one is [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Coincidentally, if you're not tied to PHP, I really suggest using a different server. node.js is a great option--it is a natural fit for this sort of problem and you can write the server-side code in JavaScript, which you already know. Even Facebook--the bastion of PHP--used a different language (Erlang) for their chat backend.

So, in summary: use socket.io. If you can, try using a different backend, although PHP is fine too.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I just got back home.  So i've looked this up and it seems great, but the only problem is that I have no idea how to implement this code or where i should put it.  Do you have a small piece of code that you could show me as an example?

Comment: I actually have a trivial chat client I wrote a while back (using node) if you want to look at that. If that's too close to what you're working on, I can extract the relevant bits here.

Comment: That would be amazing.  I just tried for about an hour trying to implement bits of code but got nowhere and am stuck back at my original function, which is very inefficient.

Comment: It's on [Github](https://github.com/TikhonJelvis/Silly-Chat). The client-side stuff is in `public/javascripts`. The interesting server-side stuff is in `chat.js` but isn't very applicable to php.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use another language you can simply do it by AJAX..

Just set an interval and update the PHP-generated div's html.. and when you send a message then the reply would be the updated div -html so that both you and the user can assure that their message is posted successfully..  There's a snippet of my own chat system code : look:

```
function updMsg() {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('chatwid');
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chatwid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","Msg.php?pg=1",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function sendMsg()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
msg=document.getElementById('msgfrm').value;
sender='<?php echo $name;?>';
xmlhttp.open("GET","Msg.php?msg="+msg+"&sender="+sender+"<?php if(isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] = 1) { echo "&a=1"; } ?>" ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById('msgfrm').value="";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('chatwid');
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chatwid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
  }
}
function interval() {
updMsg();
t=setTimeout(interval(),500);}
interval();
```

This code is actually only PHP and Javascript. It's not sufficient to include the whole jQuery Library just for using the AJAX capability. right?